# I'm trying to make a static member in my class but compiler is giving me warning that it is undefined

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm trying to make a static member in my class but compiler is giving me Error that SubjectList::X is undefined . What I'm trying to do is that , I'll make list of 2 subject . And then i gonna ask from student to choose from those two subjects. So i want to make them class property instead of object property. Because if i will not make it static every student gonna ask for subject name and code of its own.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Subject{
public:
    friend class SubjectList;
    //Subject() {}
    Subject(){
        cout << "Enter Subject name - ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter subject code - ";
        cin >> code;
    }
private:
    int code;
    string name;
};

class SubjectValue{
    friend class SubjectList;
    int value;
};

class SubjectList{
public:
    friend class Student;

    static Subject X[2];  // HERE IT GIVES ERROR.
    SubjectValue sv[2];

    set_subject();
    show_subject();
};

class Student{
public:
    friend class StudentList;

    SubjectList sub;
private:
    unsigned long int roll;
    unsigned long long int  phone;
    string name;
};

class StudentList{
public:
    Student s[2];

    set_data();
    show_data();
};

StudentList::set_data()
{
    int i ;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        cout << "Enter student name - ";
        cin >> s[i].name;
        cout << "Enter student phone - ";
        cin >> s[i].phone;
        cout << "Enter roll - ";
        cin >> s[i].roll;
        s[i].sub.set_subject();
    }
}

StudentList::show_data()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        cout << "Name of Student - " << s[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Phone of Student - " << s[i].phone << endl;
        cout << "Roll of Student - " << s[i].roll << endl;
        s[i].sub.show_subject();
    }
}

SubjectList::set_subject()
{
    int i;
    int value[2];
    cout << "Enter 1 for the subject you want to choose. \n";
    //cout << "Subject " << (i+1);
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cin >> value[i];
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        sv[i].value = value[i];
    }
}

SubjectList::show_subject()
{
    int i;
    cout << "Subjects choose by student are - " << endl;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (sv[i].value == 1)
        {
            cout << X[i].name << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    StudentList s;
    s.set_data();
    s.show_data();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is the minimal necessary to reproduce the problem?  Did you define `X` anywhere?

Comment: You should have a lot more errors than that one unless you are not posting the code you are testing.

Comment: You are *declaring* `X`, but since it is `static` you also need to *define* the memory storage for it, which the code shown here is not doing.  Outside of the `SubjectList` class, you need to add this definition: `Subject SubjectList::X[2];`

Comment: _static_ members must be initialized explicitly, always outside the class

Comment: I guess the op is using a compiler that forgives not declaring and defining members without return values. I've never seen it before....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define `SubjectList::X` somewhere below the declaration.

```cpp
class SubjectList {
    static Subject X[2];
};

Subject SubjectList::X[2];
```

If C++17 is available you can use `inline` keyword.

```cpp
class SubjectList {
    inline static Subject X[2];
};
```

Detailed explanation : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static